# Dynamic amount of operation

Tags: transactions, go-sdk

How can I add multiple operations in one transaction using the Go SDK? I am trying to add a dynamic amount of payment operations under 1 transaction and that seems to be not possible in Go as it's building a function.

I am new to Go, so please let me know if there is any way to add multiple operations dynamically inside one transaction.

In my code I added 4 operations manually. I want to know how to build them dynamically using a loop.

```
paymentTx, err := build.Transaction(
    build.SourceAccount{recipient.Address()},
    build.TestNetwork,
    build.AutoSequence{SequenceProvider: horizon.DefaultTestNetClient},

    build.Payment(
        build.Destination{AddressOrSeed: Reciver2},
        build.CreditAmount{cd.AssestTransfer.Asset[0].Code, issuerSeed, cd.AssestTransfer.Asset[0].Limit},
    ), build.Payment(
        build.Destination{AddressOrSeed: Reciver2},
        build.CreditAmount{cd.AssestTransfer.Asset[1].Code, issuerSeed, cd.AssestTransfer.Asset[1].Limit},
    ), build.Payment(
        build.Destination{AddressOrSeed: Reciver2},
        build.CreditAmount{cd.AssestTransfer.Asset[2].Code, issuerSeed, cd.AssestTransfer.Asset[2].Limit},
    ),

    build.Payment(
        build.SourceAccount{Reciver2},
        build.Destination{AddressOrSeed: recipient.Address()},
        build.CreditAmount{cd.AssestTransfer.Asset[3].Code, issuerSeed, cd.AssestTransfer.Asset[3].Limit},
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Hopefully it will help someone in the future.

```
    muts := []build.TransactionMutator{
    build.SourceAccount{recipient.Address()},
    build.TestNetwork,
    build.AutoSequence{SequenceProvider: horizon.DefaultTestNetClient},

    build.Payment(
        build.SourceAccount{Reciver2},
        build.Destination{AddressOrSeed: recipient.Address()},
        build.CreditAmount{cd.AssestTransfer.Asset[3].Code, issuerSeed, cd.AssestTransfer.Asset[3].Limit},
    ),
}
ops := []build.TransactionMutator{
    build.Payment(
        build.SourceAccount{Reciver2},
        build.Destination{AddressOrSeed: recipient.Address()},
        build.CreditAmount{cd.AssestTransfer.Asset[3].Code, issuerSeed, cd.AssestTransfer.Asset[3].Limit},
    ),
}
muts = append(muts, ops...)
tx, err := build.Transaction(muts...)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

paymentTxe, err := tx.Sign(recipientSeed)
```